# How fix selenium-webriver error - $ is not defined?

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, groovy, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to add an event to a button:

```
str = "a#fCoverage" // my locator
def str2 = "\$('" + str + "').addEventListener('click', function(){alert('text')});" // add event
js.exec(str2)
```

But I get this error:

> error: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: $ is not defined

Could anyone help me please?

Comment: use "window. jQuery" instead of  "$" ...

Comment: can you show example?

Answer (score 5):

Use `document.querySelector` inplace of `$`

Your code would end up

```
str = "a#fCoverage" // my locator
def str2 = "document.querySelector('" + str + "').addEventListener('click', function(){alert('text')});" // add event
js.exec(str2)
```

Answer (score 1):

`addEventListener` is a method on the `document` as opposed to `$` (which is *usually* a shorthand for jQuery).

So change `$` to `document`.

Comment: Why string "$(location.reload())" working in console but not working when i run test?
Test code: 
`js.exec('$(location.reload())')
browser.driver.executeScript('$(location.reload())')`

Comment: Again though - `location.reload` is a JavaScript command, it's got nothing to do with jQuery. You are making it much more complicated than it needs to be. `location.reload()` is all you need. As for the console, is `$` actually mapped to jQuery? Do `$ === jQuery` in the console => does it return `true`?

Comment: Yes, $ === jQuery
true

Comment: So what happens when you do `location.reload` in a test? ....why aren't you doing a `driver.navigate.refresh` (or it's equivalent in your language)?....

Comment: I just want to understand why if i'm writing in console 
$('a#fCoverage').addEventListener('click', function(){alert('text')}); // everything is fine
but if i doing the same in my test i have error ($ is not defined)
in test i use 
js.exec("my string") or browser.driver.executeScript("my string")

Comment: Currently i have a lot of locators like:
element (wait: true) { $("a#fCoverage") }
element2 (wait: true) { $("div.grey-section strong")[2] }
It's mean that i can't use document.getElemen by ID or className or samething else, it's will be very dificult, so I need use $ because it's solves all my problems  
All that i need it is add listener for some of this locators

Comment: I would ask kindly that you take a step back and understand how Selenium works. You have a clear lack of understanding here. It has a lot of finding mechanisms inside it already, you do not need to be using jQuery (which is what you are attempting to do). You are attempting to overcomplicate matters. You have also haven't taken on board my original answer - you are *still* using `$`. You have clear issues with how & when jQuery is loaded on your page, which is a huge problem because you aren't using Selenium *at all*. You are using it to execute JS...**wrong on so many levels**....