# Codeception unknown error when switching to window

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, codeception, behat

Been banging my head, I'm just trying to switch to a google sign in pop up window. These are the solutions I've tried:

**Solution 1:**

```
$I->switchToNextTab();
```

RESULT:

```
unknown error: $ is not defined
```

**Solution 2:**

```
$I->switchToWindow("name_of_other_window");
```

RESULT:

```
I'm still in the current window
```

**Solution 3:**

```
$this->I->executeInSelenium(function (\Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver $webdriver) {
    $handles = $webdriver->getWindowHandles();
    $lastWindow = end($handles);
    $webdriver->switchTo()->window($lastWindow);
});
```

RESULT:

```
unknown error: $ is not defined
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue.

Just an example below, but this is exactly how it's implemented

[image]

Comment: This looks more like a javascript error than a PHP error. Can you show your javascript code?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28670805/how-fix-selenium-webriver-error-is-not-defined might be of help

Comment: have you tried the php equivalent to driver.SwitchTo().Alert()?

Comment: @Rescis didn't work :(

Comment: Could you add a screenshot/url of the popup window so that I can take a look?

Comment: @Rescis Added! I don't think it has something to do with the window though, because I tried opening it as a new tab and tried switchToNewTab() it threw the error `$ is not defined`

Comment: It seems like I don't have JQuery on page based, on what I've read. I will trying things out

Comment: @e_mam106 Maybe this can be of some help: https://github.com/pazone/ashot/issues/93.